# Como percorrer um array de Objetos, dentro de outro Array de objetos

Tags: javascript

Olá, eu tenho dois arrays de objetos dentro de um array de objetos, e gostaria de poder acessa-los e renderizar os objetos de dentro (os objetos do objeto `obj1` e do `obj2`)

Bom, eu pensei nesses arrays como um forma de manipular duas variáveis (`obj1` e `obj2`) com seus respectivos valores para renderiza-los utilizando um map, porem o modo que eu fiz não funciona, gostaria de saber como fazer isso da maneira correta e também gostaria de saber se tem uma maneira mais fácil e simples de organizar todos esses arrays de objetos (boas praticas de codigo).

```
const teste = [
{
  obj1: [
    {
      teste: "teste",
      teste2: "teste2",
    },
  ],
},
{
  obj2: [
    {
      teste: "teste",
      teste2: "teste2",
    },
  ],
},
];

console.log(teste.map((e) => e.map((x) => x.obj1)));
```

Desde já Obrigado !

Comment: Mas a questão é como percorrer essa estrutura com `for` ? ou é o que em especifico ? O que está a tentar fazer com esses arrays ?

Comment: Isac entao, eu tinha pensado em usar um map por que a ideia é o seguinte, eu tenho dois componentes (em React) que vao aparecer juntos na tela e ambos tem dados fixos (ex: titulo, descrição imagem) e ao invés de passar essas props para esses componentes ao chamar o componente (ex <Card title="titulo />) eu colocaria todas essas informações nesses arrays e poderia renderiza-las nos nois componentes usando um map ficaria algo assim 

teste.map((e) => {
 <Card title={e.title} />
})

entendeu ?

Answer (score 2):

Boa noite amigo, esse seu objeto aí é meio confuso, mas você vai conseguir interar por ele dessa forma:

```
teste.forEach(obj => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        obj[key].forEach(teste => console.log(teste))
    })
})
```

Comment: entendi, mas então essa estrutura que fiz, vc sabe uma outra forma de melhora-la ? pq a ideia é colocar dois arrays com seus respectivos objetos em apenas uma unica variável, mas esse jeito que eu fiz esta muito confuso.